# In javascript, how can I call a function anytime someone updates the page?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to run a javascript function anytime other javascript on the page is run.  This is to be able to post-process the dynamically generated content.  I can't simply do the post-processing after the page loads, because I need to apply my post-processing to the content that is generated by javascript that does load another page.

Alternatively, can I register a callback to be called when a click is done on any part of the page and after all the other onclick events have been processed?

I'm doing this for a greasemonkey script to make an internal web page more usable.

Comment: Excuse if this sounds rude, but if the web page is **internal**, why make a greasemonkey script instead of just changing (aka fixing) the page?

Comment: I've submitted bugs and change requests, but I've received no response for 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of the events `DOMNodeInserted` or `DOMSubtreeModified` to identify something changing on the page.

And you may attach an `onclick` event to the window.
Alternatively, you could only attach it on elements with the inline attribute `onclick` in it.

Comment: I think `document.onclick` is what I want.  It appears that events can be caught at multiple levels of the DOM.  With `DOMNodeInserted`, I'd be afraid of having _too_ many callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the (few) options to solve this is to use a `setInterval()` that polls for changes to the document...  There are not solid cross-browser events that will inform you of document changes.

If you are looking for changes / elements added to a `<div>` for instance you could use the `.innerHTML` of that div and compare length, etc to search for new elements.

Comment: How about a global, page-wide `onclick` callback?

Comment: And how can I check if the page changed?  Is there a client-side embedded browser version number or do I have to scan the document again?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can run your function once when the DOM is ready and then bind it to the `ajaxComplete` event so that it runs anytime a script loads data via AJAX from the server.